# Get standard error output from jUnit in intellij / android studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I am running tests in Android Studio, although I believe this is also an Intellij question as well. The test pass fine, but upon closer inspection I see that there is a stacktrace being outputted to the test console. Unfortunately when the tests complete the output is cleared. Does anyone know where I can find these logs? I looked in the Intellij logs but the jUnit runner doesn't appear to be logging them there, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of a buggy behavior in IntelliJ IDEA. It primarily happens with fast running tests. It was reported as a bug via [IDEA-66683 Output from fast running parameterised JUnit test is not grouped correctly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66683) and numerous duplicates. That ticket was marked as being fixed for the forthcoming IntelliJ IDEA version 15. It will likely get merged into Android Studio at some point.

The bug primarily happens on fast running tests. For example, in the following test, when I run all the tests in the class, I will not see the `System.err` output (and sometimes not even the `System.out` output) *when looking at that individual test's results*:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest()
{
    System.err.println("Std Err from simpleTest");
    System.out.println("Std out from simpleTest");
    new RuntimeException("A sample Exception").printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I will for this test, with its *added delay at the end*:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest()
{
    System.err.println("Std Err from simpleTest");
    System.out.println("Std out from simpleTest");
    new RuntimeException("A sample Exception").printStackTrace();
    try {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);} catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
}
```

With a delay of 1 second, I did not see the results. But with 2 seconds, I did. My *suspicion* is that there is an issue that IntelliJ IDEA needs some time to "grab" the output for each individual test and put it in some sort of buffer or collection for that test. But if the test ends before that process complete, the output is not displayed for that individual test's results. This seems to be more of an issue for `System.err` than `System.out`, but on occasion I have seen it occur for the latter.

That's the bad news. The good news is that **the output can be seen in other ways...**

If you run an individual test, usually you can see all the output by selecting the test name. If you run all tests in a class, as I mentioned above, the `system.err` output may not all be visible *when viewing an individual test's results*. However, if you view all the tests combined output by selecting the class name at the top of the tree, you can see the combined output which (should) have the output from all the tests. Unfortunately, it is intermingled. Worse case, run the test individually so you can see the details more clearly.

Comment: thanks, it was unclear to me if this was a bug with Intellij or of I was missing something.